# Error: Cannot write configuration file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I am new to ASP.NET MVC 5.
I am trying to enable SSL in my project but it is not working. Whenever I try to set it to true it throws an error:

```
**Filename: \\?\C:\Users\{username}\OneDrive\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\ASP.NET MVC Projects\Vidly\.vs\config\applicationhost.config
Error: Cannot write configuration file**
```

Comment: Try moving your project out of your OneDrive path. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/134518/visual-studio-does-not-like-onedrive-files-on-dema.html

Comment: Have you looked into a Git based Source Control?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This guide helped me when i was trying to do the same;
the important detail is that you enable ssl in the project properties.
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4b0136/a/

Answer (score 2):

This problem occurs when you turn on OneDrive and allow it to back up (auto-sync) your Documents folder. This process moves your Documents folder into the OneDrive and turns it into a One Drive hot-sync folder, unknowingly to the end-user.

This special folder regulates what can be written to it and is blocking visual studio's configuration file write process.

By simply moving the solution out of the folder you will solve the problem OR turn off the One Drive sync to your Documents folder.

Answer (score 0):

try to save the project in differnt location and make check it has debug mode.

Answer (score -1):

I had similar problems.
I turned off OneDrive, then added ssl in the **applicationhost.config** under bindings:

```
<binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44327:localhost" />
```

Now at least ssl was set to true in the project properties.
Still couldn't load, so I turned it off via the gui, and then on again, and voila it worked!
Hope this helps if anyone else gets the prob.